# Any way to set Sentry programmatically in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sentry

I have my app which is written in the spring.
Now I want to set a sentry when in my `application.properites` is set property `version=prod`.

Currently I have configured a `sentry.properties` with DSN, and it's working fine. But how I can run this programmatically?

Comment: What means do you use to set `version=prod`? The recommended way to run Sentry is to leave the DSN blank in development (so remove it from the `sentry.properties` file) and only provide it in production by adding `SENTRY_DSN` environment variable or `-Dsentry.dsn` Java Property via your normal deploy mechanisms.

Comment: @Brett thanks, I'll must do this like you propose.